# How to use GridLayout to make the following page?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I wanted to try out the GridLayout in my program but sadly I don't clearly understand it, Hope someone helps.

[image: layout]

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) section.

Comment: You need to post the code that you tried so that we can help you correct it.

Comment: A GUI is generally created by using multiple panels of components with each panel using an appropriate layout manager. For example, you would create a panel for the two buttons and that panel would probably use a FlowLayout. Maybe the top-level panel with use a GridLayout for the right/left pane. For the left pane I might use a BorderLayout and add the table to the CENTER and the button panel to the PAGE_END. For the right panel again a BorderLayout with components in the PAGE_START, CENTER and PAGE_END.